# add an array of collection inside collection with Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get all clubs that belongs to a federationPresident.

So, I have:

```
$federation->associations
```

which gets me a collection of associations,

```
$association->clubs that gives me a collection of clubs
```

I would like to do :

```
$federation->associations->clubs, but it doesn't work
```

What I did:

```
  foreach ($federation->associations as $association) {
       foreach ($association->clubs as $club){
           $clubs->push($club);
   }
 }
```

This works, but I think I'm missing something, and I could do it easilier.

Thing is I will have to do it a lot of time in my code, so, this is not very elegant...

Any Idea how to do it better?

Association Model:

```
public function clubs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Club::class);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a model for clubs and does your association model have a method setup which relates it to clubs?

Comment: yes, if you need, I can include, it, but relations work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eager loading.  You use dot notation to relate nested models.

```
$federations = Federation::with('associations.clubs')->get();
```

And now everything is nested for you...

```
foreach ($federations as $federation) {
    foreach ($federation->associations as $association) {
        foreach ($assocation->clubs as $club) {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Another way would be to use the `hasManyThrough` relating method.  It does work with 2 has-manies.

In your `Federation` model.

```
public function clubs()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Club::class, Association::class);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am doing. I am looking for something to avoid the 2 foreach

Comment: Then you can setup a relation in your federation model for clubs which would be a `hasManyThrough`.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: yes, I think this is what I am looking, for, but I am not sure it works with 2 has many relationships

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`Has Many Through`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)
relation ...

which will get you all the clubs that belongs to the `associations` of the `federation`